# Зачем интерфейсу нужны дженерики?

Tags: java, интерфейс, generics

Узнал что у интерфейса можно определить дженерики, попробовал сделать это в коде, но так и не понял где это используется(и как), т.к. это ни на что не повлияло. 
P.S. Еще вчера узнал что у методов в интерфейсе может быть тело, если метод статический. Это практически убирает различие между абстрактными классами и интерфейсами(кроме наследования и final переменных).

Comment: В интерфейсе могут быть сигнатуры методов, в параметрах и в возвращаемых значениях которых могут быть дженерики

Comment: Это очень странный вопрос. Обобщения нужны интерфейсам для того же, для чего и классам. Посмотреть как используется можно в стандартной библиотеке. А методы по умолчанию не обязательно должны быть статическими.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дженерики нужны для обобщения. Это относится и к классам, и к интерфейсам.

Пример интерфейса с дженериком:

```
interface MyExecute<T> {
    void execute(T obj) throws Exception;
}

class ThreadExecute<T> implements MyExecute<T> {
    @Override
    public void execute(T obj) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("obj: " + obj);

        // Тут мы индивидуально, в зависимости от типа объекта делаем обработку
        if (obj instanceof String) {
            // ...
        } else if (obj instanceof List) {
            // ...
            
        } else {
            // ..
        }
    }
}

class ProcessExecute<T> implements MyExecute<T> {
    @Override
    public void execute(T obj) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}

// Можно имплементироваться от интерфейса с указанием конкретного типа:
class ProcessExecuteStr implements MyExecute<String> {
    @Override
    public void execute(String obj) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ThreadExecute<String> thread = new ThreadExecute<>();
        thread.execute("abc");

        ThreadExecute<List<String>> thread2 = new ThreadExecute<>();
        thread2.execute(Arrays.asList("1", "a", "@"));    

        MyExecute<Integer> process = new ProcessExecute<>();
        process.execute(+100500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с написанным выше. Можно было бы везде пользоваться `Object` типом, а после его приводить к нужному типу(если бы не было джинериков), но тогда появится потенциальная ошибка во время выполнения(`ClassCastException`), а когда есть джинерки, ошибка будет на этапе компиляции.

Пример: у вас есть `List<String>`, а вы при вызове метода `add()` вставляете `Integer`, то когда есть джинерки, эта ошибка проявится на этапе компиляции, а если нет, то на этапе выполнения.